# cellForRowAtIndexPath never called

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios4

I've subclassed UITableView to create my own data retrieval system, as described in Apple's own Core Data tutorial, but I've hit a problem. The substitute cellForRowAtIndexPath method in my custom table never gets called, not even when I call reloadData or setNeedsDisplay. I've been hunting around for solutions to this one, and it seems that this error can be caused by a multitude of problems. However I've checked all the ones I can find and cannot see anything missing. Can anyone tell me what's likely to be wrong?

P.S. I know the UITableViewDataSource protocol needs to be in triangular brackets, but I couldn't find out how to show triangular brackets on the page without deleting the text between them.

**H-File**

```
@interface DataTable : UITableView <UITableViewDataSource> {
    NSMutableArray *list;
}
```

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *list;

@end

**M-File**

```
@implementation DataTable
```

@synthesize list;

-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)rect Style:(UITableViewStyle)style{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:rect style:style]){
        list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.dataSource = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
  return [list count];
  }
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  static NSString *cellID = @"Cell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
  if (cell == nil){
      cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                     reuseIdentifier:cellID] autorelease];
  }

  CH *this = (CH *)[list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  cell.detailTextLabel.text = [this.clusterName mutableCopy];
  return cell;
  }

-(void) dealloc{
    [list release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, think I've found it. Basically, you can't set the datasource delegate in that part of the program. Need to do it from its owning view controller.